# plotting histogram by a data frame

Tags: r

I am a new user of R and I am running the last 7 days this language using the *mixdist* package for the modal analysis of finite mixture distributions. I am working on nanoparticles thus the R is for the analysis of particle size distributions recorded by a particle analyser I am using to my experiments.
My problem is illustrated below:
Firstly I am collecting my data from excel (raw data)

```
Diameter    dN/dlog(dp) frequencies
4.87    1825.078136 0.001541926
5.62    2363.940947 0.001997187
6.49    2022.259831 0.001708516
7.5     1136.653264 0.000960307
8.66    363.4570006 0.000307068
10      255.6702845 0.000216004
11.55   241.6525906 0.000204161
13.34   410.3425535 0.00034668
15.4    886.929307  0.000749327
17.78   936.4632499 0.000791176
20.54   579.7940281 0.000489842
23.71   11.915522   0.00001
27.38   0           0
31.62   0           0
36.52   5172.088    0.004369665
42.17   19455.13684 0.01643677
48.7    42857.20502 0.036208126
56.23   68085.64903 0.057522504
64.94   87135.1959  0.07361661
74.99   96708.55662 0.081704712
86.6    97982.18946 0.082780747
100     95617.46266 0.080782896
115.48  93732.08861 0.079190028
133.35  93718.2981  0.079178377
153.99  92982.3002  0.078556565
177.83  88545.18227 0.074807844
205.35  78231.4116  0.066094203
237.14  63261.43349 0.053446741
273.84  46759.77702 0.039505233
316.23  32196.42834 0.027201315
365.17  21586.84472 0.018237755
421.7   14703.9162  0.012422678
486.97  10539.84662 0.008904643
562.34  7986.233881 0.00674721
649.38  6133.971913 0.005182317
749.89  4500.351801 0.003802145
865.96  2960.469207 0.002501167
1000    1649.858041 0.001393891
Inf     0               0
```

using the function

```
pikraw<-read.table(file="clipboard", sep="\t", header=T)
```

After importing the data in R I am choosing the 1st and the 3rd column of the above table :

```
diameter<- pikraw$Diameter
frequencies<-pikraw[3]
```

Then I am grouping my data using the functions

```
pikgrp <- data.frame(length =diameter, freq =frequencies)
class(pikgrp) <- c("mixdata", "data.frame")
```

Doing all these I am going to plot the histogram of this data

```
plot(pikgrp,log="x")
```

and there something strange happens: The horizontal axis and the values on this look fine although the y axis of the graph appear the low values of the frequencies as they are and the high values with a cut decimal lowering the plot.

Have you got any explanation on what is happening? Probably the answer could be very simple although after exhausting my self and losing a whole weekend I believe that I have all the rights on my side.

Comment: I apologise for the data view, it was my mistake I have below the data as viewed in R

Comment: Diameter dN.dlog.dp. frequencies
1      4.87  1825.07814 0.001541926
2      5.62  2363.94095 0.001997187
3      6.49  2022.25983 0.001708516
4      7.50  1136.65326 0.000960307
5      8.66   363.45700 0.000307068
6     10.00   255.67028 0.000216004
7     11.55   241.65259 0.000204161
8     13.34   410.34255 0.000346680
9     15.40   886.92931 0.000749327
10    17.78   936.46325 0.000791176
11    20.54   579.79403 0.000489842
12    23.71    11.91552 0.000010000
13    27.38     0.00000 0.000000000
14    31.62     0.00000 0.000000000
15    36.52  5172.08800 0.004369665

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I get exactly what I expect. Perhaps you should post an image of the problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are reading your data wrong. Try this:

```
pikraw <- read.table(file="clipboard", sep="", header=T)
```

That is, change the `sep` argument to `sep=""`. Everything worked fine from there.

Also, note that using the clipboard as `file` argument only works if you have your data on the clipboard. I recommend creating a .txt (or .csv) file with your data. That way you don't have to have your data on the clipboard everytime you want to read it.